# About Covariance

Tags: covariance

I'm coding in python for a project. I have all my data and run an "optimize.leastsq". 
I want the uncertainty in cov[1,1] and cov[0,0]. Is it just the square root of these matrix elements or is there more involved? Picture attached below

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does "uncertainty" mean in this context?

Comment: I'm afraid I dont know how else to qualify it. It is the uncertainty in the measurement, propagated from errors.